# Draw a histogram of the characters in input

Tags: c++, c++20

It's sometimes fun to implement the exercises from K&R in C++.  It's certainly interesting to see what C++ makes easier and what's still difficult.

I've had a go at Exercise 1-14 in the second edition:

> **Exercise 1-14**. Write a program to print a histogram of the frequencies of different characters in its input.

The extra challenge from 1-13 also applies here:

> It is easy to draw the histogram with the bars horizontal; a vertical orientation is more challenging.

I also chose to make my histogram bars logarithmic.

My code looks fairly slick for gathering the data, but I wasn't very satisfied with the output half:

```
// A program to print a histogram of the frequencies of different
// characters in its input.  K&R(2) exercise 1-14.

#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <ranges>


template<typename T>
using counter = std::map<T, std::size_t>;

static bool isprint(char c)
{
    return std::isprint(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));
}

int main()
{
    auto hist = counter<char>{};
    std::ranges::for_each(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{std::cin},
                          std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{},
                          [&hist](char c){ ++hist[c]; });

    auto const keys = hist | std::views::keys;
    auto const values = hist | std::views::values;
    auto const max_val = std::ranges::max(values);

    // width of the scale column
    unsigned count_width = static_cast<unsigned>(std::ceil(std::log10(max_val)));

    // scale to fit a 24-line display (but just assume it's wide enough)
    auto constexpr rows = 23u;
    auto const scale = std::log(static_cast<double>(max_val - 1)) / rows;

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(0);
    for (auto i = rows;  i;  --i) {
        // scale bar
        auto const threshold = static_cast<std::size_t>(std::exp(i * scale));
        std::cout << std::setw(count_width);
        if (i % 2 == rows % 2) {
            std::cout << threshold;
        } else {
            std::cout << "";
        }
        std::cout << '|';
        // character columns
        for (auto v: values) {
            std::cout << (v >= threshold ? '*' : ' ');
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    // histogram key
    std::cout << std::setw(count_width + 1) << '|';
    for (auto k: keys) {
        std::cout << (isprint(k) ? k : ' ');
    }
}
```

When fed its own source code, it produces this output:

```
406| *                                                            
   | *                                                            
241| *                                                            
   | *                                                            
143| *                                                            
   | *                                                  *         
 84| *                                                 **         
   | *                  *             * * *   *        **         
 50|**                  *             * ***   *    *  ***         
   |**                  * *           * ***   *   **  ****        
 29|**                  * *           * ***   * * **  ****        
   |**     **           ***           * ***  ** * **  ****        
 17|**     **           *** *         * ***  ** ****  ****        
   |**     **     *     *****        ** ******* ***** ****        
 10|**    ***     *     *****        ** ******* ***** ******   * *
   |** *  ***     *     *****        ** ******* ***** *******  * *
  6|** *  ***     *     *****        ** ************* ******** * *
   |** *  ***   * * **  *****        **************** ******** ***
  3|** *  *** *** * **  *****        **************** ******** ***
   |****************** *******   ** ***************** ************
  2|****************** *******   ** ***************** ************
   |**************************************************************
  1|**************************************************************
   |  "#%&'()*+,-./01234:;<=>?AKRT[\]_abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}
```

N.B. The [C++20 library support](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2020) in GCC 11 is not sufficiently complete for this, so GCC 12 is required (or any other compiler with good C++20 support).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's some surprisingly compact but still very readable code! Very good use of C++20's ranges.

## Casting numbers

You are performing several explicit casts. While I don't think there is anything wrong with them, one is at least unnecessary: [`std::log()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log) and many other math functions have overloads that take integers, and will cast to `double` automatically for you. So you don't have to do that yourself.

You use `auto foo = static_cast<sometype>(somevalue)` in many places, which is good, but you didn't do this for `count_width`, where you specified the type twice. This is a bit dangerous, as if the two types don't match you will might have an undesirable implicit cast happening.

Also, since you use `count_width` as an argument for `std::set()`, which takes an `int`, it might be better have it be an `int` itself:

```
const auto count_width = static_cast<int>(std::ceil(std::log10(max_val)));
```

## Use a `std::array` while counting

When counting how many times each character occurs, a `std::map` is inefficient. Since you know there are only [`UCHAR_MAX` + 1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) possible characters, you can create a `std::array` of that size. This avoids expensive lookups every time you want to update a counter.

After counting you can consider either converting the result into a `std::map`, or just iterating over the `std::array` and ignoring any element that has a count of zero. The latter would make your code a bit more complicated, although you could probably still do it with ranges. While a [`std::views::enumerate`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2164r0.pdf) would have been very helpful, you can still do things in C++20 like:

```
std::array<std::size_t, UCHAR_MAX + 1> hist{};
std::ranges::for_each(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{std::cin},
                      std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{},
                      [&hist](char c){ ++hist[static_cast<unsigned char>(c)]; });

auto values = hist | std::views::filter([](auto count){ return count != 0; });

for (auto& value: values) {
    auto key = static_cast<char>(&value - &hist[0]);
    std::cout << key << ": " << value << "\n";
}
```

You could create some helper functions to make that look less hacky.

## Split the code into multiple functions

You can split `main()` into a function that calculates the histogram and one that prints it.

## Missing newline

Your program doesn't print a newline after the histogram key.

## Infinite loop when the input is empty

Your program goes into an infinite loop when the input is completely empty. This is caused by applying `std::ranges::max()` to an empty view. I think the solution is just to check if `hist.empty()` right after the `for_each()`, and quit the program if that returns `true`.

## Incorrect output when every count is 1

When every character in the input occurs exactly once, then `count_width` is zero, which causes every other line of the output to be shifted by one.

The simple solution is just to add a `std::max(1u, ...)` to the calculation of `count_width`.

## y-axis count is off by one

The y-axis only shows the maximum count minus 1. This is because you literally subtract 1 from `max_val` when calculating `scale`, not because of floating point imprecision, although the latter is something you should worry about as well. Instead of subtracting 1, I would just add 0.5 to `max_val` when calculating `scale`.

## Consider using `std::format()`

Since your code relies on C++20, you could consider using `std::format()` (or [{fmt}](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) if your standard library doesn't support it yet); it makes aligning text much easier. For example:

```
for (auto i = rows;  i;  --i) {
    auto const threshold = static_cast<std::size_t>(std::exp(i * scale));
    if ((i - rows) % 2)
        std::cout << fmt::format("{:{}}|", "", count_width);
    else
        std::cout << fmt::format("{:{}}|", threshold, count_width);
    for (auto v: values) {
        std::cout << (v >= threshold ? '*' : ' ');
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

With C++23, you can even [format ranges](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2286r8.html). This would allow you to do something like:

```
for (auto i = rows;  i;  --i) {
    auto const threshold = static_cast<std::size_t>(std::exp(i * scale));
    std::print("{:{}}|{::s}\n",
        threshold,
        count_width,
        values | std::views::transform([threshold](auto v){
            return v >= threshold ? '*' : ' ';
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Tricky with the y-axis count - if I scale to get that right, I end up with no bar quite reaching that height.  Presumably due to truncation of floating-point values.

Comment: I think I worked it out - use `std::exp(i * scale)` for the label, and `std::exp((i-.5) * scale)` for the threshold to draw a star.

Comment: That might also work :)

Answer (score 5):

C++20 ranges and views are not available for all compilers yet. The default C++ compiler on Ubuntu 22.04 does not support them because it is gcc11 and not gcc12.

Since the problem is in the first chapter of K&R it is considered quite simple and can be safely put into one function, the main function, but personally I would divide it up into input and output functions. That might make the code a little more readable. It takes a little searching to find where the code is actually doing the input from `stdin (std::cin)`.

This part of the output loop is complicated enough to be a function:

```
        // scale bar
        auto const threshold = static_cast<std::size_t>(std::exp(i * scale));
        std::cout << std::setw(count_width);
        if (i % 2 == rows % 2) {
            std::cout << threshold;
        } else {
            std::cout << "";
        }
        std::cout << '|';
```

That could make the output `look slicker`.

The variable `keys` is created long before it is actually necessary:

```
    // histogram key
    auto const keys = hist | std::views::keys;
    std::cout << std::setw(count_width + 1) << '|';
    for (auto k : keys) {
        std::cout << (isprint(k) ? k : ' ');
    }
```

Comment: I should have said that I used GCC 12 for this - sorry for omitting that!